# rx-java create two files and zip them from String input

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I need to write a function that gets a string as an input, then generate two files, and zip them together. For non reactive code it would like:

```
void func(String input){
    byte[] a = generateFileForA(input);
    byte[] b = generateFileForB(input);
    byte[] zip = zipFiles(a,b);
    doSomethingWithZip(zip);
}
```

How can I implement such logic in a reactive way using rx-java?

Comment: Why do you want to put this into Rx and why haven't you simply put this method call into Rx (like in a `subscribe()` call)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on your specific usecase, or the benefits of using Rx for this particular work (other than simplyfying threading potentially).

However something like this pseudo code would work :

```
public class Zip {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Zip zip = new Zip();
    final Disposable d = zip.func("some input")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.single())
            .subscribe(result -> { }, System.out::println);
}

Single<byte[]> func(String input) {
   return Single.zip(
           generate(input, new File("myFileA")), 
           generate(input, new File("myFileB")), 
           this::zipFiles);
}

private Single<byte[]> generate(String input, File output) {
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
        // Do Work
        return new byte[0];
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()); /* Parallel execution */
 }

private byte[] zipFiles(byte[] a, byte[] b) {

    // Do work
    return new byte[0];
}
```

}